# C++ inline minimalist thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is a "minimal thread pool" I came up with to compare with a colleague's approach using Rust's Rayon's `par_bridge()` to automatically parallelize looping over an indexed container (a vector in his case).

This is basically a `std::for_each` with `std::execution::unsequenced_policy` (in this case), but you have access to the guts of the pool (you can decide on chunk size, number of threads, .. waiting for executors in C++26).

```
bool process_one(string filePath); // can be a lambda passed as argument too

void loopFilesVect(vector<string>& filesVect, int packSize, int nbThreads)
{
  int nTh = nbThreads;
  uint32_t N = filesVect.size()/* #items */, c = N/packSize /* #packs */;
  mutex mtx; vector< unique_ptr<std::latch> > sigs; // unique_ptr for automatic deletion of latches

  int k = 0; atomic_uint32_t success = 0;
  auto process_chunk = [&](const uint32_t start, const uint32_t end) {
    cerr<<std::format(" Worker {} : {} to {}\n", start/packSize, start,end-1);
    for(unsigned int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
      if(process_one(filesVect[i])) success++;
      else cerr<<" error processing "<<filesVect[i]<<"\n";
    }
    { scoped_lock<mutex> g{ mtx }; sigs[k++]->count_down(); }
    cout<<std::format(" Worker {} done\n", start/packSize);
  };
  
  std::vector<std::future<void>> workers; // std::async() -> future
  #define submitPack(start,end) { sigs.emplace_back(new std::latch{1}); \
    workers.push_back( std::async(std::launch::async, process_chunk, start, end )); }
  
  cout<<std::format(" Processing {} file{}..", N, N==1?"":"s");
  { if(nTh>c) nTh = c; auto it = sigs.cbegin(); int n = 0;
    for(n = 0; n < nTh; n++) // use up allowed task count
      submitPack( n*packSize, std::min((n+1)*packSize,N) );
    (*it)->wait(); it++; // wait for 1st task to finish, so we can start a new one without exceeding nTh
    n = nTh/* n*packSize already processed */; c-- /* now last pack makes n*packSize > c*packSize */;
    while(n*packSize < N) { // do nothing if all packs already submitted
      submitPack( n*packSize, n==c ? N/*last one*/ : (n+1)*packSize );
      if( n==c ) break; // previous line just submitted last pack
      (*it)->wait(); it++; // wait for oldest task to finish
    }
    sigs.back()->wait(); // wait for the last pack to be processed
  }

  cout<<std::format("Done ({} successfully processed)\n", success.load());
}

loopFilesVect(vFiles, thread::hardware_concurrency()/2, 200);
```

Performance was similar to Rust's, which was satisfying (given the power of Rayon).

It uses the lightest synchronization object available (a `latch{1}`), and it's all in front of you : you can make this as sophisticated as you want (from adding atomic counters for statistics like `nProcessed`, `nFailed`, .. to using an elaborate synch mechanism beyond `scoped_lock` - but then maybe you need a Pro-thread pool).

Do you see anything wrong/improvable with this implementation ?

Comment: It is certainly legal to write a single line that says `a = x; /* foo */ b = y; /* bar */`. But if you feel the need to repeatedly insert intra-line explanations, maybe it's time to take a step back. Why is this code tricky enough to need all those explanations? Would dedicating a full comment line above the code be an effective way to convey what the Reader needs to know? Would longer identifiers, or breaking out a helper function, lead to more self-explanatory code? As an exercise you might try copying out just the code (no comments), then edit _that_ for clarity.

Comment: My comment is that. That code is really hard to read. Please space things out. This is not a code gold you don't want to use the minimal number of lines. Spread it out make it easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code style

This code is terrible to read; the formatting is inconsistent, sometimes there are multiple statements per line, sometimes not. There are comments in the middle of lines, making it easy to miss things.

I recommend you use an automatic code formatter to reformat your code.

Also avoid unnecessary abbreviations and one-letter variables. Exceptions are only things that are very commonly used, like `i` for a loop variable. However, you have `N`, `n`, `k` and `c`, and it's very hard to tell what those are from just their name alone.

## This function does too many things

You claim "this is a minimal thread pool", but it's not. It's a function that only works on a vector of strings, and calls `process_one()` on each of them in parallel. What if you have something that is not a vector of strings? What if you want to call some other function than `process_one()`?

I would try to create something that's just a generic thread pool, without hardcoding what kind of container to work on or what function to call on each of the elements. That will result in much more reusable code.

## Avoid macros

`submitPack()` does not need to be a macro, just make it a lambda.

## Use `std::size_t` for sizes, counts and indices

You are mixing `int`, `unsigned int` and `uint32_t`. Be consistent, and prefer to use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for sizes, counts and indices.

## It's more complicated than necessary

There's a mutex, latches and futures. You shouldn't need all three. Furthermore, you are starting a new thread for each chunk, which has some unnecessary overhead.

I would just start `nTh` tasks that each pick chunks themselves until all chunks have been processed. Something like:

```
auto process_chunks = [&]() {
    while (true) { 
        std::size_t start;
        std::size_t end;
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
            if (k > c)
                return;
            start = k * packSize;
            end = std::min(start + packSize, N);
            k++;
        }
        for (std::size_t i = start; i < end; ++i)
            process_one(filesVect[i]);
    }
}

std::vector<std::jthread> workers;
workers.reserve(n);

for (std::size_t n = 0; n < nTh; ++n) {
    workers.emplace_back(process_chunks);
}

// Wait for all work to finish:
workers.clear();
```

I've used [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) here for simplicity, but you can do the same with `std::async()`. And instead of using a mutex, you could even use a `std::atomic<std::size_t>` to track the next chunk to process.

## `loopFilesVect()` is called with parameters in the wrong order

When you call `loopFilesVect()` at the end of your code, you passed the number of threads and the chunk size in the wrong order.

This is a common problem when passing two parameters of the same type; the compiler cannot tell that there is a problem here. You can avoid this in several ways. Maybe the simplest is to not have a parameter for the number of threads, but just the chunk size, and always use up to `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` threads. Another way is to define a `struct` that contains the parameters, so you can use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers):

```
struct thread_pool_parameters {
    std::size_t packSize;
    std::size_t nbThreads;
};

void loopFilesVect(vector<string>& filesVect, thread_pool_parameters parameters) {
    …
}

loopFilesVect(vFiles, {.packSize = 200,
                       .nbThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() / 2});
```

Comment: Thank you for the review ! I agree in general with the comments about style, the real thing looks nothing like this, be assured. I am not a fan, however, under the pretense of "clarity", of stretching a 1-active-line (ususally a syscall)-function to fill up half a page. Being able to visually dominate a slice of code helps my understanding, scrolling a mile.. doesn't. Here the "style" I chose went with my boasting of an "inline thread pool" to go, which, admittedly, went a bit far (I did invert args in function call during the hair cut).

Comment: As per the strategy, you're absolutely right, restarting threads is costly, the eager-worker polling for meals to eat is of course better (that's exactly what I do in my main program), this was an experiment to compare Rust & C++ (I'm still very impressed by Rayon). I tried `jthread` and `async` : async startup is like 3 times faster on Windows 10 (we're talking pennies). As per your size_t comment, I know it's the wise choice, but I have no sense of range with size_t. Somehow I'm repeatedly surprised when I look it up. I like knowing my program can handle 4 billions files in a single folder..

Comment: some other places where 4 billions looked like a (remote) risk (a lock-free queue with ever-increasing pop/push cursors - for perf.) I chose uint64_t and I can sleep better..

Comment: Regarding the macro use, until C++ takes reflection seriously, I have no shame coding with macros. A two-liner is no issue at all, but lambdas are indeed a must for longer/more complex logic.

Comment: [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is *guaranteed* to be able to index every byte in memory. So if you have a container of filenames, `std::size_t` is guaranteed to be able to index every element in that container. This is why it's the wise choice. Macros are very [error-prone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17043190/5481471), and in C++ they are often easily avoidable. Instead of `#define submitPack(start,end) {…}` you could write `auto submitPack = [&](auto start, auto end) {…};` and all the issues you had with the macro are gone.

Comment: `size_t` use : there is context (I use a hand-rolled "vector" of wide strings to represent a folder (paths) with auto-split functionality to be able to keep threads busy, a thing of beauty, I can share this gadget if you want), the unit32_t had more to do with guarantees about #max of files in a single folder that our program can handle, but it resides in memory, so you're fundamentally right. An external eye is always beneficial, it would seem ! Thank you for insisting.

Comment: Macros are not only error-prone but can turn into near black-magic, I'm talking about the far opposite side of the spell : when a macro is simple text-shortening-replace (nothing to debug, really) that saves on space and is used locally (not more that a dozen lines after def., by the way, I removed the #undef, bad style :). In this risk-free setup, I actually wouldn't mind the small perf. gain over a lambda/function call. A maco this simple is actually a case of KISS.

Comment: There is no perf gain when you compile with optimizations enabled; the compiler will be able to inline the lambda calls.

Comment: True for simple lambdas. Case in point : to traverse the folder tree, I use a recursive lambda, which *has to* be declared as `std::function` (for now). I wonder if this is inline-able..

Comment: With `std::function` neither Clang nor GCC seem able to inline recursive calls. But in C++23 you can write recursive lambdas, and those will be inlined (of course, as long as the compiler can see at compile time if the recursive call will happen). Anyway, you mention lots of decisions you made because of code not mentioned in your question. We can of course not review based on things we cannot see, so our answers will only reflect the posted code in isolation.

Comment: That's what I thought. I do digress. I guess my point is that macros are "born to be inlined" (sic). Thank you for the answer and, again, for the review.